# How to access and set iFrame element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Currently, I am using jquery to make a certain class/span editable:

```
$(function(){$('.test').editable({editClass:'tryThis',type:'textarea'})});
```

That works great.  Now, what I would like to do is put the source into an iFrame (ID=iTarget).

How would I access this class now?

I tried:

```
$(function(){document.getElementById('iTarget').$('.test').editable({editClass:'tryThis',type:'textarea'})});
```

But that doesn't work, I must be missing something.

Comment: It takes some time to update that rate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Define an event on iFrame element with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218404/define-an-event-on-iframe-element-with-jquery) (not an exact duplicate, but I think the concept of accessing an iframe's contents remains the same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) method:

```
$("#iTarget").contents().find(".test").editable({
    editClass: "tryThis",
    type: "textarea"
});
```

Comment: Actually, I plugged it in and it worked, and now it doesn't. In my iFrame, I've got a dv that surrounds everything called "tgt", and then the span of .test is beneath that.  Does that make a difference?

Comment: It sounds like it should still work, find should include all descendants. Do you know what could have changed between the first time and the second time you tried it?

Comment: Weird... iTarget is my iFrame. <div id="tgt"><p><span class="test">ttttt</span></p></div>

Comment: iFrame looks like: <iframe src="target.html" width="450" height="500" id="iTarget">

Comment: I am putting it within the $(document).ready(function() function.  Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: Yes, that could be it. You need to make sure that the iframe has loaded before trying to modify its contents. The iframe will load after the parent page has loaded. Can you move your editable code into the iframe itself? It would make things much easier. You should delay running your code after the iframe's onload event fires.

Comment: hmmm. that makes sense.  I'd rather keep the code out of the iFrame - is there a way to hold of the ready function until the iFrames load?

Comment: OK - inside the parent page, I put: $('iframe').load(function() { // write your code here.... }

that seems to make it work. Many thanks!