# How to add a click event to p elements in iframe (using jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, iframe

How to add a click event to `<p>` elements in iframe (using jQuery)

```
<iframe frameborder="0" id="oframe" src="iframe.html" width="100%" name="oframe">
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Define an event on iFrame element with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218404/define-an-event-on-iframe-element-with-jquery)

Comment: are you trying to do this without adding any code to the content within the iframe?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a special jQuery function that does that: [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/). See the example for how it's works.

Comment: Thanks, $('#iframe').contents().find('p').click()

Answer (score 1):

Your best best bet is to invoke the iframe AS LONG AS it's part of your domain.

iframe.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.MyMethod = function()
            {
                $('p').click();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

And then use

```
document.getElementById('targetFrame').contentWindow.MyMethod();
```

To invoke that function.

another way is to access the iframe via `window.frames`.

```
<iframe name="myIframe" src="iframe.html"/>
```

and the javascript

```
child_frame = window.frames['myIframe'].document;
$('p',child_frame).click(function(){
    alert('This click as bound via the parent frame')
});
```

That should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to add this, as a complete, copy-paste solution (works on Firefox and Chrome). Sometimes it is easy to miss to remember to call the event after the document, and so the iframe, is fully loaded:

```
$('#iframe').on('load', function() {
    $('#iframe').contents().find('#div-in-iframe').click(function() {
        // ...
    });
});
```

The iframe must be on the same domain for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

By giving a reference to the IFrame document as the second parameter to jQuery, which is the context:

```
jQuery("p", document.frames["oframe"].document).click(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

To access any element from within an iframe, a simple JavaScript approach is as follows:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow;
// Get HTML element
var iframeHtml = iframeDoc.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
```

Now you can select any element using this html element

```
iframeHtml.getElementById("someElement");
```

Now, you can bind any event you want to this element. Hope this helps. Sorry for incorrect English.