# Getting IFrames with urls in R shiny

Tags: r, iframe, shiny

I have made an application which uses Iframes. I frame page contains lots of links inside. I want to get the urls when I click one link inisde iframe . How can we approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [contents](https://api.jquery.com/contents/), you can bind an event to your iframe like:

```
$('#MyIframe').contents().find('a').click()
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708969/how-to-add-a-click-event-to-p-elements-in-iframe-using-jquery) question.