# Jquery live() with contents inside iframe not working

Tags: jquery

I have an iframe, inside that iframe occurs dom elements additions by ajax.

With $("iframe").contents().find() y can access and work with .remove() .html() .click() without problems. But i can't bind events for the new elements added by ajax with live();

my jquery code:

```
    $("#iframe_id").contents().find("a .tittle").live('click',
        function(e)
        {
              //stuff
        }
    );
```

But viewing the iframe in a new windows and workinkg with:

```
$("a .tittle").live('click',function(e)
        {
              //stuff
        }
    );
```

It works...

Any idea????

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Maybe this would help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218404/define-an-event-on-iframe-element-with-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find("a .tittle").live('click'
```

won't work, regardless of iframes. `live()` can only be called on a direct selector, not one that comes from traversal methods like `find`. [Doc](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

> DOM traversal methods are not supported for finding elements to send to .live(). Rather, the .live() method should always be called directly after a selector

This is in my opinion a poor, misleading bit of interface design, which is why I'd recommend using the [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method in preference to `live()` in all cases.

Cross-document (into an iframe) event handling is also likely to be a problem. jQuery is not really designed for interacting with documents from code in different documents. I would recommend loading a copy of jQuery into each document, and handling events and DOM manipulation entirely within the code of that document.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your time, i didn't know that. Perhaps one day jquery decide change that...  Thanks for the recomendatio too.

Answer (score 2):

#### First thought

It could be that the iframe contents has not loaded when your try to bind the live handler to it. Try:

```
$("#iframe_id").load(function(){
    $(this).contents().find("a .tittle").live('click', function(e){
        //stuff
    });
});
```

I don't think that this is actually the problem.

#### Second thought

as per [the live function docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

> DOM traversal methods are not supported for finding elements to send
>   to .live(). Rather, the .live() method should always be called
>   directly after a selector, as in the example above.

This means you cannot do `$('.something').find('.somethingElse').live(...);`. Instead you must do `$('.something .somethingElse').live(...);`

Comment: Thanks you very much for your time, i didn't know that. Perhaps one day jquery decide change that...

Comment: live() is deprecated, one should use on() instead. http://api.jquery.com/on/ Example: $(document).on("click", "a.offsite", function(){ alert("Goodbye!"); }); (from http://api.jquery.com/live/)